# Update state of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When changing the state of an element from true to false coming from a checkbox, performing the setState does not update the screen -- it is necessary to press another element on the screen with state to later update the value of the checkbox.

```
let arrayNiveis = [
        {
            id: 1,
            codigo: 16,
            filhos: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    codigo: 17,
                    filhos: null,
                    marcado: false,
                    menu: 1,
                    nivel: 1,
                    nome: "Listar",
                    opcao: 2,
                    pai: 1
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    codigo: 19,
                    filhos: null,
                    marcado: false,
                    menu: 1,
                    nivel: 2,
                    nome: "Disponível",
                    opcao: 2,
                    pai: 1
                }
            ],
            marcado: false,
            menu: 1,
            nivel: 0,
            nome: "MANUTENÇÃO DE SERIAIS",
            opcao: 2,
            pai: null
        }
    ];

const handleCheckBox = (e: any) => {
        let eleId = parseFloat(e.target.id);
        arrayGrupoNiveis.map((nivelItem: any) => (
            nivelItem.filhos.map((filho: any) => {
                if (filho.id == eleId) {
                    filho.marcado = !filho.marcado
                }
            })
        ))
        setArrayGrupoNiveis(arrayGrupoNiveis);
    };
```

When setting the state in setArrayGrupoNiveis, the screen is not updated with the same value.

Comment: Don't use `map` for side effects. Either set something to the array returned by `map`, or use `forEach`.

Comment: Cheatsheet: `map` is for producing another array of the same length, `filter` is for getting an array of the same type of element of the same or lesser length, `reduce` is for building some other type of data out of your array, and `some`, `find`, `findIndex`, `at` are for finding things, and `forEach` is for doing something with each element when you don't need a resultant array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting an update is because `setState` uses `Object.is()` internally. This means that it is comparing the reference of the array in memory. By looping over `arrayNiveis` and mutating it, you aren't changing the reference to the array. So when you use `setArrayGrupoNiveis()`, React doesn't find a difference and hence the re-render isn't triggered.

What you should do is make a copy of this array and then use that in the `setsetArrayGrupoNiveis()` hook which would change the reference and hence trigger the re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Bro, what are you trying to do?!
do you want to change values inside the array? are you sure this code is working

```
filho.marcado = !filho.marcado
```

another thing is you need to use return when you have nested maps, specially when you are using it as a function.

try to use return, it might work.

```
return filho.marcado = !filho.marcado
```